# OBJ not showing up in blender

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

I have imported an OBJ file into Blender and it just won't display. [image]

I can see the UV'sin UV editing [image]

And I can see how many has faces, verts and edges it has in Modeling [image]

I have tried moving it, scaling it, switching view ports..... Just can't see the model itself anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: selected all mesh objects, pressed "." on my numpad and it zoomed onto it. However, the 3D cursor is not there and honestly I have no idea where the 3D model is locate on the grid. When I try to move or rotate using shortcuts it works (however scaling doesn't) and if I use the the move, scale, rotate options instead of using the shortcuts, It does not display the axis arrows to do so.

Comment: Also can't view in Sculpt mode or Texture paint mode even if I press "." on my numpad